# php mongodb connection in windows using wamp

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I have the following error. My php version is 5.6, a x64 bit system and wamp. I downloaded the pecl driver "5.6 Thread Safe (TS) x64" and pasted inside ext folder in php and also edited the php.ini file.Restarted the local server. but still the error is coming.Anyone have any solution
the error is "The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled."

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me because of wrong dll file.

Ensure the following things and download the correct dll file.

1) Your php version

2) Your system architecture (64 or 86)

3) Whether Thread safety enabled or not (You can check this in phpinfo())

[Find DLL here](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb)